# Having trouble appending to in the correct place

Tags: jquery

I am trying to append some HTML so that my tables will sort using tablesorter. Currently the tables are sorting if you click on the first row of the table information, I would like viewers to be able to click on Donation Total to sort there . . .  please see demo to see what I mean: 
http://jsfiddle.net/jelane20/kt8jzg9e/8/

If you look at the demo then click on Donation Total nothing happens, if you click on the amount in the first row under donation total then it sorts.

```
<table width="100%" bgcolor="#003399" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="1" border="0">
  <tbody><tr><td>
    <table width="100%" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2" border="0">
      <tbody>
         <tr bgcolor="#003399">
            <td colspan="4" class="white"><b>Click on the Group for more information: </b></td>
         </tr>
         <tr bgcolor="#eeeeee">
             <td>&nbsp;</td>
             <td><b>Group Name</b></td>
             <td><b>Group Captain</b></td>
             <td><b>Donation Total</b></td>
         </tr>
         <tr bgcolor="#ffffff">
           <td></td>
           <td><a href="#">test1</a></td><td>test test</td>
           <td>$20.00</td>
         </tr>
         <tr bgcolor="#eeeeee">
          <td></td>
          <td><a href="#">test2</a></td>
          <td>test test</td>
          <td>$50.00</td>
         </tr>
         <tr bgcolor="#eeeeee">
          <td></td>
          <td><a href="#">test3</a></td>
          <td>test test</td>
          <td>$30.00</td>
         </tr>
      </tbody>
     </table>
    </td>
   </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Here is the script . . .

```
var $existTable= $('table td table');

var $newTable = $('<table id="newTable"><thead></thead><tbody></tbody></table>');
$newTable.find('thead').append($existTable.find('tr').eq(2));
$newTable.find('tbody').append($existTable.find('tr:gt(1)'));
$existTable.parent().append( $newTable );


$newTable.tablesorter();
```

This will make more sense if you look at the Fiddle however - 
http://jsfiddle.net/jelane20/kt8jzg9e/8/

Thank you so much!

Comment: Suggest you format the HTML to make it easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/kt8jzg9e/9/) is this what you wanted?

**JS CODE**

```
var $existTable= $('table td table');
var $newTable = $('<table id="newTable"><thead></thead><tbody></tbody></table>');
$newTable.find('thead').append($existTable.find('tr').eq(1));
$newTable.find('tbody').append($existTable.find('tr:gt(0)'));
$existTable.parent().append( $newTable );
$newTable.tablesorter();
```